# r: as.date funtion returns to NA

Tags: r, date, na, as.date

The original data looks like this
[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwa8Q.png)

This is my code

```
myformat <- "%m/%d/%y" 
UScases_B$date <-as.Date(UScases_B$date,myformat) 
UScases_B
```

The output looks like this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpjDt.png)

I also tried these code but it does not work for me.

```
 lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
 Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
 Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
 Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")
 Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","English")
```

My system language is English. R studio is the latest version.

I really appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: The location to learn what the `%`-codes all mean is unintuitively [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html). Those codes (for the most part) work in `as.Date(., format=)` format strings.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the original data is already in the default format required by `Date` class.  It doesn't need any `format`

```
 UScases_B$date <-as.Date(UScases_B$date)
```

The default `format` is `%Y-%m-%d` where `%Y`- 4 digit year, `%m`- 2 digit month and `%d`- 2 digit day

Comment: I tried this method just now but it still does not work. Thank you so much.

Comment: @T1an-T1an I think you tried on the already assigned values i.e. `NA` instead of the original data.  Please try on original dat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Date-object, you have to use  `UScases_B$date <-as.Date(UScases_B$date)`, as @akun suggested.

If you want to reformat your dates from 2020-01-21 to 01/21/20, you have to use `UScases_B$date <- format(as.Date(UScases_B$date), "%m/%d/%y")`.